# Detecting HTTPS under ExpressJS works only with 1 out of 4 methods

Tags: node.js, ssl, express, heroku

I recently added a SSL certificate to my website. After adding HTTPS support I wanted to redirect people to the secure connection. I googled to see how to detect HTTPS and found on Stack many different ways. It seams they work for others but they don't work for me. Out of 4 ways to check for a secure connection, only one worked.

What doesn't work for me:

- **req.secure**: always return **false** even if i put manually https://
- **req.connection.encrypted**: always return **undefined** even if i put manually https://
- **req.protocol**: always return **http** even if i put manually https://

What works:

req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] is the only way that actually returns reality.

Knowing this I redirect to a secure connection in the following way:

```
// Check if the connection is secure, if not, reddiret to a secure one.
function requireHTTPS(req, res, next) {
    if(process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production') {
        if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] !== 'https') {
            return res.redirect('https://' + req.get('host') + req.url);
        }
    }

    next();
}

app.use(requireHTTPS);
```

In any other way that I mentioned above I would get a redirect loop because even after redirecting to HTTPS, the above methods would return **false** or **http**.

My question is: why the other methods don't work?

Tech spec:

- Website: https://simpe.li
- Hosted on Heroku
- Node versions: 4.1.1
- Express: 4.13.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heroku exposes HTTPS for you, but then proxies standard HTTP to your worker. The `req.headers['x-forwarded-proto']` method is the correct way to detect HTTPS under Heroku. Similarly, you'll need to access the `x-forwarded-for` and `x-forwarded-port` if you need the originating IP address and port.

The [Heroku Routing](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing) documentation has more details on their routing structure.